# Excel : script to identify text in one column (based on regex) and paste it in the next column once found

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have an excel file with more than 10,000 columns of text like this(example):

```
Identified a potential Security Vulnerability CVE-2018-1231
```

Is there anyway i can identify the columns having `CVE` and write the whole `CVE-2018-1231` in the next column by writing a regex or formula?

Comment: Yes there are several ways of doing this. Why don't you go and do some research, try something and then post back when you have a specific problem?

Comment: Hi @SJR, thanks for your response. I did some research and found that it can be done using ISNUMBER and SEARCH(example):
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("apple",A2)),"Apple",
What i am not sure about is how do i use this in numbers after "CVE-XXXX-XXXX"?

Comment: Yes I don't think that will work for your situation although you can use wildcards in the SEARCH formula (but doesn't distinguish numbers from anything else). I think either the answer below or Regexp is probably the way to go here.

Answer (score 1):

for cell A1 containing your example:

```
=if(isnumber(search("CVE";A1));right(A1;13);"")
```

with , as delimiter

```
=if(isnumber(search("CVE",A1)),right(A1,13),"")
```

Comment: Hi, Many thanks for your response. I tried using this but didn't work. please have a look [here](https://imgur.com/a/pgrSKXf).

Comment: possibly due to the fact that you are using , as delimiter instead of ; like I do. Change all ; to , and try again

Comment: The formulas are missing a closing parentheses (and therefore cannot work).

Comment: corrected the missing parentheses, thanks for the remark

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula in column B (assuming column A contains the data)

```
=IFERROR(MID(A1,SEARCH("CVE",A1),13),"")
```

This will even work if the `CVE` is not necessarily in the end. It will work for both examples below:

```
Column A                                                            | Column B
Identified a potential Security Vulnerability CVE-2018-1231         | CVE-2018-1231
Identified a potential Security Vulnerability CVE-2018-1232 aeuia e | CVE-2018-1232
```

---

If your CVE number is not constantly 13 characters you must use:

```
=IFERROR(MID(A1,SEARCH("CVE",A1),IFERROR(SEARCH(")",A1,SEARCH("CVE",A1)+1),IFERROR(SEARCH(" ",A1,SEARCH("CVE",A1)+1),LEN(A1)))-SEARCH("CVE",A1)),"")
```

This formula will cut out the CVE until a closing parentheses or a space comes or until the end of the text.

Comment: Just one last question. We are using 13 digits string in output, and considering "1231" (the last part) will only be 4 digits, when i have 5 digit long string in the last part and change the "13" digit limit to 14, it takes one extra character in the end f our digit as well. 
[HERES](https://imgur.com/a/1Nz1c2v) an example. Can you suggested something to remediate this?

Comment: As you will see, the last ")" in B1 is useless.